# How to hide columns in flutter DataTable?

Tags: flutter, datatable

I need to hide columns in a flutter DataTable but cannot seem to find any examples on how to do so.

the following is the code snippet that i am using. Is there some way to set then to hidden or something.

When i remove the column completely i get an assertion that the row calls are not equal to the column count. So i am not sure what i should do? Any help is much appreciated.

```
child: DataTable(
      columnSpacing: 10,
      headingRowHeight: 30,
      dataRowHeight: 30,
      horizontalMargin: 0,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          numeric: true,
          label: Text('Id'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Date'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Amount'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Type'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Label'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Category'),
        )
      ],
      rows: vm.transactionList
          .map(
            (tran) => DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  tran.id.toString(),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  tran.tranDate(),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  tran.amount.toString(),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                _getTransactionType(tran.type),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  tran.label.toString(),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Icon(
                  tran.category.icon,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by actually removing the unneeded DataColumn and DataCell elements. I did not find any property that could be used to hide or make a column visible so removing them completely was the next best option.

Comment: but i implement dynamic header and row , so still needed the data of ID from first row

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering like this - Wrap your DataColumn and the corresponding DataCell in an if condition.

```
if (your condition)...[
    DataColumn()
], 

if (your condition)...[
    DataCell()
],
```